# Referring to a new worksheet with variable name

Tags: vba, excel

So what I want to do is like this in visual basic VBA for Excel:

```
Dim var As String
Dim wsNew as Worksheet  

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet

var = Range("A34").Value
Worksheets(wsNew).Cells(1, 2) = var
```

But in this case line: `Worksheets(wsNew).Cells(1, 2) = var`
gives error

> Run-time error 13, type mismatch

I don't want to give string name to the new worksheet because then I would always have to rename the sheets. So is it possible to refer to a worksheet in VBA with variable name instead of string name.

Comment: You could do `wsNew.Cells(1, 2) = var` but then you haven't defined `wsNew`.

Comment: `var` is a bad name for a `String` variable. It reads as though it's a `Variant` type. Actually, though, it's a bad name for *any* variable. Instead, name it something meaningful, e.g. *managerName* or *productDescription*...etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to assign the Worksheet Object to a variable then you can refer directly to it in the code. You'll also need to explicitcly reference the `Activesheet`, otherwise the code will not work as expected, especially in this case.

```
Dim wsCurr as Worksheet
Set wsCurr = Worksheets("mySheet") 'change as needed (I avoid ActiveSheet whenever possible)

Dim myVariable As String
myVariable = wsCurr.Range("A34").Value

Dim wsNew as Worksheet      
Set wsNew = Sheets.Add(After:=wsCurr)

wsNew.Cells(1, 2) = myVariable
```

Also, notice how I changed `var` to `myVariable`. CallumDA has a great point in the comment below your post about naming variables.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Dim wsCurr as Worksheet
Set wsCurr = Worksheets("mySheet") 'change as needed (I avoid ActiveSheet whenever possible)

Dim myVariable As String
myVariable = wsCurr.Range("A34").Value

Dim wsNew as Worksheet      
Set wsNew = Sheets.Add After:=wsCurr

wsNew.Cells(1, 2) = myVariable
```

worked like a charm, many thanks to all of you.

Only this smallest thing was something Excel gave me error:

```
Set wsNew = Sheets.Add After:=wsCurr
```

So by changing that to this:

```
Set wsNew = Sheets.Add(After:=wsCurr)
```

Made it to work perfectly.

Comment: it's because you need to place arguments in parens when assigning to an object. I forgot that in my original answer but edited it in.